# Hiding multiple columns in Excel based on the value of a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get columns to hide in a worksheet based on the value in a certain cell. This value could range from 1 to 30, and different columns are hidden for each possible option. I have the following code, but it doesn't seem to work all the time, and then sometimes it only hides some of the columns in the range, but not all (like if 5 was in cell AA1, then sometimes AN:AR will hide and AS:FC will not be hidden). If anyone has any ideas, I would appreciate the help. Thanks!

I have a sample workbook at: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8qPItN2DU0BZ3B0LW1XUS1BMFk/view?usp=sharing

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Range("AA1").Value = 1 Then
    Columns("O:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("O:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("AA1").Value = 2 Then
    Columns("T:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("T:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("AA1").Value = 3 Then
    Columns("Y:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("Y:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("AA1").Value = 4 Then
    Columns("AD:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("AD:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("AA1").Value = 5 Then
    Columns("AI:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("AI:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("AA1").Value = 6 Then
    Columns("AN:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("AN:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("AA1").Value = 7 Then
    Columns("AS:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("AS:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("AA1").Value = 8 Then
    Columns("AX:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("AX:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("AA1").Value = 9 Then
    Columns("BC:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("BC:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("AA1").Value = 10 Then
    Columns("BH:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("BH:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("AA1").Value = 11 Then
    Columns("BM:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("BM:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("AA1").Value = 12 Then
    Columns("BR:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("BR:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("AA1").Value = 13 Then
    Columns("BW:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("BW:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("AA1").Value = 14 Then
    Columns("CB:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("CB:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("AA1").Value = 15 Then
    Columns("CG:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("CG:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("AA1").Value = 16 Then
    Columns("CL:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("CL:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("AA1").Value = 17 Then
    Columns("CQ:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("CQ:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("AA1").Value = 18 Then
    Columns("CV:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("CV:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("AA1").Value = 19 Then
    Columns("DA:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("DA:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("AA1").Value = 20 Then
    Columns("DF:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("DF:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("AA1").Value = 21 Then
    Columns("DK:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("DK:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("AA1").Value = 22 Then
    Columns("DP:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("DP:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("AA1").Value = 23 Then
    Columns("DU:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("DU:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("AA1").Value = 24 Then
    Columns("DZ:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("DZ:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("AA1").Value = 25 Then
    Columns("EE:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("EE:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("AA1").Value = 26 Then
    Columns("EJ:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("EJ:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("AA1").Value = 27 Then
    Columns("EO:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("EO:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("AA1").Value = 28 Then
    Columns("ET:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("ET:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("AA1").Value = 29 Then
    Columns("EY:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
    Columns("EY:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Although an answer has been posted which might solve your problem, you better off using `Worksheet_Change` event.

Comment: Thank you, L42 - I did end up using _Change vs. _SelectionChange along with Tim's answer below. I appreciate your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like there's a pattern of 5 columns per integer increase in the value in AA1, so:

```
Dim v, sht

Set sht = ActiveSheet
v = sht.Range("AA1").Value

sht.Columns("O:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

If v >= 1 And v <= 30 Then
    sht.Range(sht.Cells(1, 10+(5*v)), _
              sht.Range("FC1")).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End If
```

Although it's not particularly clear from the question exactly what the logic for hiding/showing is.

Comment: Good catch on recognizing the pattern but I believe it actually maxes out at 29, not 30; 10 + (5 × 29) or column EY.

Comment: I didn't scroll all the way down to the end of the OP's code: I was going off the statement that the value could be between 1 and 30...

Comment: Thank you, Tim! This worked great! You were right in going off my statement that the values could go up to 30, but I should have reworded that if the value was 30 that no columns should have been hidden; so Jeeped, thank you for pointing out that error on my part! I just adjusted the code to be v <=29 and everything worked out just fine. Many thanks to all!

Answer (score 3):

You are hiding a range of columns, and as your code is executed you are hiding, then re-displaying a lot of the columns.

You would be better to firstly display all columns in the largest range (O:FC) in your example, and then only hide the ones that match your value. So you could change the if else constructs to be a select case like this:

```
Columns("O:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

select case Range("AA1").Value
    case 1:
      Columns("O:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    case 2:
      Columns("T:FC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ' Add extra cases for each possible value
end select
```

Comment: Just about to post the same answer.  Case is superior to a bunch of IF statements.

Comment: Yeah me too. Just one comment. `Columns("O:FC").Hidden = True` will suffice or `Range("O:FC").Hidden = True` will give the same result. No need to use `EntireColumn` because that is basically the entire column.